# Vscode how to disable tooltip

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I want not to watch tooltip "int printf(const char ***restrict**, ...)"

I disabled Editor > Hover settings, but not working.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to disable `Editor > Parameter Hints` option

Comment: Thx! but it didn't work.